# RegEx for matching xx:xx

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to check an time value string `08:00` or `09:10` etc.

I tried `var patt = new RegExp('^[0-9][0-9][:][0-9][0-9]');`

but this matches `08:00000` etc.

How do I get it to only march for the five character?

Comment: You don't need to enclose single characters in `[]`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add a dollar sign at the end like that:

```
var patt = new RegExp('^[0-9][0-9][:][0-9][0-9]$');
```

Anyway here's a more compact regex to that does the same:

```
var patt = /^\d{2}:\d{2}$/;
```

Comment: thanks that's what I was looking for  I also had this which didn't work too well  /^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-4]):([0-5][0-9])(:[0-5][0-9])?$/.test(inputField.value);